# Why doesn't Blender render the the geometry I've created properly

Tags: rendering, modifiers

I have a model that consists of the following:

1. A tire tread: A polygon plane with an array modifer and a curve modifier to bend it into the shape of a wheel and a mirror modifier to mirror it from one side of the tire to the other
2. A wheel hub (a rim): A polygon plane with a mirror modifier on it and an array modifier set to object with a null rotated to create the other parts of the wheel.
3. 1 & 2 are grouped and instanced 3x to create the other wheels
4. A simple polygonal box cut in half and mirrored for the body of the car

The model is obviously not done, but why isn't it rendering properly?

[image: blender modifiers not rendering properly]

[image]

Comment: Check your modifiers. Some of them probably have different visibility settings between viewport and render (the little boxes that look like camera and eye).

Comment: Thanks for that idea, but the modifiers have the standard visibility set (visible, and visible in render). You can also see how one of the rims is getting moved to a completely different place, and none of the treds (the tire rubber) are rendering properly. I did just switch to Cycles Renderer and that worked like I would expect it to, but it takes a lot longer to render.

Comment: so cycles rendered correctly but the blender internal did not? That is odd. Please upload the blend to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ I'd like to see what's going on.

Comment: Looks like the normals are inverted. In edit mode press ctrl N to make normals consistent

Comment: @David : [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4769" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4769/)
cegaton : thanks for the idea, I tried it (a few different ways) and it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this is an interesting one. It seams blender *displays* [DupliGrouped](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupligroup.html) objects **incorrectly**, and *renders* them **correctly**.

You made one wheel, using a *Curve* modifier and a BezierCircle to form the tread of the wheel. Then you distributed the wheel group to the other three places using DupliGroups.

The trouble is you did not group the BezierCircle (you had three and the one being used in the modifier is not in the group), so when you distribute the
wheel around the *Curve* modifier on the tread is still pointing to the first BezierCircle. Which because the origin of the curve is now in a very different spot then the wheel object, the curve modifier is making a mess instead of a tire.

Simply add the *BezierCircle.001* object to your group named "Group" and all the wheels will render correctly.
To add it to the group select the BezierCircle.001, then in  the object tab of the properties panel scroll down to the *Groups* section and press the large *Add to Group* button. Choose your group named "Group" from the list.
[image]